# Creating a header file for android activity class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have added few native methods to my android `Activity` class.Now I want to create the header file for that `class`.

I get the following error while creating the header file from command line.

```
C:\AndroidProjects\JniTest\bin\classes>javah -classpath .;
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platforms\android.jar com.example.jnitest.JniTest
Error: cannot access android.app.Activity
class file for android.app.Activity not found
```

Basically unable to access the activity class form the jar.

Please advice.

Comment: see [Tutorial: Android JNI](http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/04/tutorial-android-jni/) here u can find step-by-step guide for creating JNI header.

Comment: Thanks..Anyways...I got id done myself..it will be like this
C:\AndroidProjects\JniTest\bin\classes>javah -classpath C:\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6\sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar;.  com.example.jnitest.JniTest

Comment: @amj - Please post your findings as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in Eclipse,

Go to > Run | External Tools| External Tool Configurations Under Program create new configuration by clicking small icon.

Name it.

Location would be : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javah.exe

Working Directory would be: ${workspace_loc:/My_First_NDK/bin/classes} and

Arguments would be: -classpath ${workspace_loc:/My_First_NDK/bin/classes} -bootclasspath "C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar" -v -d ${workspace_loc:/My_First_NDK/jni} com.mypackage.ndk.HelloNDK

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The command would be (use backslashes (`\`), instead of forward slashes (`/`) while using Windows `cmd`):

```
javah -bootclasspath $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platforms/android-17/android.jar -classpath bin/classes com.example.jnitest.JniTest
```

You should use `-bootclasspath` instead of `-classpath`, since `android.jar` re-implements [Java Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library).

Assumptions:

- Your current directory is: `C:\AndroidProjects\JniTest`;
- Your Android SDK is installed in `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` (`%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%` for Windows);
- Your target API Level is `android-17`.

Please modify your command accordingly.